# Medic feat: does it only work for one hit die, or more?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, unearthed-arcana, rests, hit-dice

The Medic feat (from [Unearthed Arcana: Feats for Skills](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-SkillFeats.pdf)) has the following description:

> During a short rest, you can clean and bind the wounds of up to six willing beasts and humanoids. Make a DC 15 Wisdom (Medicine) check for each creature. On a success, **if a creature spends a Hit Die during this rest**, that creature can forgo the roll and instead regain the maximum number of hit points the die can restore. A creature can do so only once per rest, regardless of how many Hit Dice it spends.

Can a creature benefit from this feat for multiple hit dice?

**Example:** I short rest, and someone with the Medic feat binds my wounds. I use 3 Hit Die of d10 (Fighter).

**Do I recover 30 HP, or only 10+2d10?**

Comment: The text of the feat (specifically the last sentence) seems to pretty explicitly answer your question. Can you clarify what your confusion is?

Comment: @RyanThompson "can only do so once per rest" I can spend 3 die at once, so does this count as once?

Comment: For the record: you also restore your Con mod on each Hit Die.

Comment: @FenrirG please don't answer in comments

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**You heal 10+2d10.**

Part of your emphasis on the feat description:
"...if a creature spends **a Hit Die** during this rest..." Singular.

Last sentence of the Medic feature:

> A creature can do so only once per rest, regardless of how many Hit Dice it spends.

RAW on using hit dice to heal after a short rest (emphasis mine):

(PHB Chapter 8, Page 186)

> A character can spend one or more Hit Dice at the end of a short rest, up to the character’s maximum number of Hit Dice, which is equal to the character’s level. For each Hit Die spent in this way, the player rolls the die and adds the character’s Constitution modifier to it. The character regains hit points equal to the total. **The player can decide to spend an additional Hit Die after each roll.**

This means the dice are rolled one by one and you decide to continue or not after seeing the first roll.

Also note that the Medic feature is used **instead** of rolling the die.

> ... that creature can **forgo the roll** and instead regain the maximum number of hit points the die can restore.

Note: If you are unsure whether the Medic adds your CON modifier to healing like i am check [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117322) question.

Answer (score 14):

## 10+2d10

This line reveals how it works (recall that the feature references a single die):

> A creature can do so only once per rest, regardless of how many Hit Dice it spends.

You will gain the maximum roll from only 1 die meaning that you must roll the other two.

It is worth noting that you don't restore 3d10 without the medic feat but instead restore 1d10 + 1d10 + 1d10. This is relevant since you can choose to expend another hit die after the rolls (under Short Rest in the Player's Handbook):

> For each Hit Die spent in this way, the player rolls the die and adds the character’s Constitution modifier to it. The character regains hit points equal to the total. The player can decide to spend an additional Hit Die after each roll.

Comment: I thought you can spend all 3d10 at once?

Comment: @Vylix You can, but that can be inefficient. If you need 30 more hp you know you should spend like 5-6 hit die. Deciding to roll 5 and then getting 3 10s in a row wastes 2 hit die. You better roll them one by one and decide when to stop instead. You can do so in a single short rest.

Comment: @nwp so does this answer still stands if I choose to spend all 3? Can only do so once per rest, spending 3 at once surely counts as once?

Comment: @Vylix The point is that you can spend 1 and then choose to spend another and then choose to spend another. That way you know the previous rolls before deciding if you want to roll the next, so you have more information and can make better decisions. Usually you just keep rolling hit dice until you have enough hp or run out, which is strictly better than announcing the number of hit dice you will use before starting your rolls. Maybe you roll all 1s on your 3 hit dice which makes you change your mind and you now want to roll a fourth. You can do that.