# Does the Medic feature negate the +CON modifier healing when resting?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, healing, unearthed-arcana, rests

Somewhat related question [here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117311)

Medic feature:

> During a short rest, you can clean and bind the wounds of up to six willing beasts and humanoids. Make a DC 15 Wisdom (Medicine) check for each creature. On a success, if a creature spends a Hit Die during this rest, that creature can forgo the roll and instead **regain the maximum number of hit points the die can restore.** A creature can do so only once per rest, regardless of how many Hit Dice it spends.

Using Hit Dice during a short rest:

> A character can spend one or more Hit Dice at the end of a short rest, up to the character’s maximum number of Hit Dice, which is equal to the character’s level. For each Hit Die spent in this way, the player **rolls the die and adds the character’s Constitution modifier to it. The character regains hit points equal to the total.** The player can decide to spend an additional Hit Die after each roll.

My confusion is the missing modifier on medic feature. Is it assumed that you'd add your CON modifier to healing or is that a drawback of the Medic feature.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### You add your constitution modifier to the maximum roll of the dice

As you have noted, the medic feat allows you to forgo the roll and

> regain the maximum number of hit points the die can restore.

Well, to determine the maximum number of hit points the die can restore, we have to know mechanically how the die restores hit points. That procedure, as you have noted, is:

> the player rolls the die and adds the character’s Constitution modifier to it. The character regains hit points equal to the total.

Since that procedure is how we determine how many hit points a hit die restores, we would take the maximum possible result of that procedure to get "the maximum number of hit points the die can restore". The maximum result of that procedure is determined by the maximum value of the die plus your constitution modifier.

Thus, you do not ignore your constitution modifier when using the medic feat.